# Use dotnet Core package in dotnet Framework app

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have an app built on dotNetFramework using FileSystemWatcher.
The app is intended to be cross-platform. I does work well on Windows but I encounter an issue on MacOs.

The reason is that the "MacOS dotNetFramework" (ie Mono) FileSystemWatcher is not working properly (https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=574564)

I have recently tested the dotNetCore implementation of FileSystemWatcher and this one is working exactly as it should.

So my question is : is there a way to use the dotNetCore implementation of FileSystemwatcher in my app instead of the dotNetFramework one ?

I've tested few things unsuccessfully.

I begin to wonder if I'm not going to make a dotNetCore console app that runs the FileSystemWatcher and that passes messages to the dotNetFramework Window App through IPC or whatever.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot use a `.Net Core` libraries with `.Net Framework`, you may try to a portable library.